# Raspberry Pi H264 to HLS Stream

Tags: python, camera, streaming-video

We need to use Raspberry Pi camera for 2 tasks.
One is getting image, the other is watching camera remotely.

Ways are getting RTSP from Raspberry Pi camera (which when I did it become difficult to take pictures), or HLS video from H264 record that we record with using Python.

Is there a way to create hls files from h264 records while h264 file is still recording?

Answer (score 1):

[v4l2rtspserver](https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2rtspserver) is a RTSP Server for V4L2 device capture supporting HEVC/H264/JPEG/VP8/VP9.

```bsh
sudo modprobe -v bcm2835-v4l2
sudo v4l2rtspserver -v -P554 -G640x480x5 -ulive /dev/video0
```

You can view the live stream in VLC: **rtsp://127.0.0.1/live**